# How to engineer a bimodal continuous feature for use in Decision Tree?

Tags: cart, continuous-data, feature-engineering, bimodal

I have a predictor that exhibits **"bimodal" behaviour**. How can I engineer this feature to improve performance within a Decision Tree?

---

For an intuitive example, consider how a binary flag of **"moves house in next 6 months?"** may correlate with a continuous variable of **"change in income over last month"**. This may yield a distribution like the following:

[image: binned data to illustrate bimodal nature of continuous data]
*(continuous data has been binned; simulated to illustrate bimodal nature of data)*

- those that get **larger increase in income** (e.g., get promoted) are more likely to move house (e.g., up-size) than those whose income remains unchanged
- those that get **larger decreases in income** (e.g., made redundant) are also more likely to move house (e.g., move back in with parents)

My trouble is that when using a Decision Tree (non-negotiable), cuts are applied on nodes to find the best value at which to split. However, due to the bimodal nature of the feature, the cuts cannot successfully split the data well enough.

Question: **how can I engineer this feature to improve performance within a Decision Tree?**

---

I have considered:

- adding an additional feature that states whether the change is positive or negative
- converting the data into categories (bins), which can later be one-hot-encoded

Comment: Decision trees are known to have sub-par accuracy precisely beucase of their simple rules. Have you tried some other method to compare results?

Comment: Due to technical limitations, our company needs the model to be translatable into "simple" code - I think this limits us to Decision Trees (i.e., conditional IF-ELSE logic) or Logistic Regression (i.e., a simple linear combination of [scaled] predictors). However, from what I understand about these algorithms under-the-hood, they can not cope very well with features that have "complex" structure (i.e., in my example, the distribution is U-shaped, and not monotonically increasing). Can you think of any techniques to re-engineer this feature?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, except maybe trying to recode your variables to avoid this situation. For ex. add an additional variable (bought new house, moved to parents) if you have such information. Or any other such information that can be used to separate into better groups.

Comment: Yep - I got that impression from the lack of answers! Of course, more features would solve the problem, but sometimes it's not possible (due to lack of resources) and we have to make do.

Comment: I came up with a solution - it's not perfect, but it has made the data more usable than it was

Comment: Revert to the original variables.  In your example you lost information by subtracting one month's income from another's to yield "change of income." Drop the derived variable (the change) and use the two actual incomes for explanatory variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Take the absolute value of the feature.** So instead of a feature of

$$x_1$$

you'd have

$$\mid x_1 \mid$$

With `pandas`, this can be done using `df[feature].abs()`

---

Note that this assumes the data is symmetric about $0$, i.e., the probability density function for $x>0$ is $f(x)$, and for $x<0$ is $f(-x)$; if this assumption is true, then this will make the data far more linearly separable than in its current form.

Comment: This might work, but this completely changes the interpretation of the variable. You lost important information, since you cannot distinguish who's change in income is positive or negative anymore.

Comment: You could create 2 variables: abs(x) and sign(x).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by bimodal behaviour you mean target variable bimodal behaviour, I would proceed as following:

- Make a regressor that predicts de absolute value of X_1 as mentioned by other answers
- Make a binary classifier that tries to predict if the value of X_1 is going to be positive or negative

The second estimator helps recoverying information lost during the .abs() transformation